# C - Reading text file line by line to pointer array, getting BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c, xcode, pointers, exc-bad-access

I write in Xcode. My code should read a text file line by line into a pointer array *ar[]. I used a simple loop that reads each character with getc() to c, and c to *ar[i]. if c!= '\n' *ar[i] is incremented. Otherwise, both *ar[i] and i incremented. I've added 'printf' after each step for easy traction.  **The problem:** the program reads the first line to *ar[0], but once i is incremented to 1, I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2,address=0x10000000000). MAC's VIM gives Bus error:10.  Something happens in the incrementation that I can't put my finger on.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 10



int main()
{

    FILE *file;
    int i = 0;
    char *ar[MAXLINE];
    char c;


    file = fopen("/Users/ykeshet/Desktop/lab/alice30.txt", "read");

    while ((i < MAXLINE) && ((*ar[i]) = c = getc(file)) != EOF){
        if (c != '\n'){
            printf("%c",c);
            (*ar[i])++;
            }
        else{
            printf("%c",c);
            (*ar[i])++;
            i++;
            }
        }

    printf("\n");

}
```

[This is the output I get (first line)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E72LF.png)

[That's the variable's state in the debugger:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sFTG.png)

Comment: when calling function: `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: Thanks. In this specific case I know the operation was successful because the first line was read.

Comment: BUT the code does not know if the operation was successful.  So the code will try reading from the `file` when the file failed to open.

Comment: OK. Added NULL check. same results

Comment: I'd suggest pasting the actual text of the output and the debugger state as text rather than images linked to from an external site.

Comment: Btw. if the first line of your file is `ALICE'S ADVENTURES IN WONDERLAND\n`, I count **33** characters (incl. `\n`). At the beginning of your sample code, you `#define MAXLINE ` **`10`**. Got it?

Comment: Oje. I just realized, it's even more worse. (Didn't notice the `*` in `char *ar[MAX_LINE];`...)

Comment: An iron basic thumb rule in C: If you intend to access the contents of a pointer you have always to ensure that the pointer does point to allocated memory. This may be either memory allocated by the compiler (i.e. global or local variables, e.g. arrays) or memory allocated by `malloc()` (or something similar).

Comment: ...and if a pointer points to a local variable, don't forget to keep in mind it's life-time. (The life-time of a local variable ends with the `}` which closes the last `{` after which the variable is declared.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Illustrating the errors here:

```
char *ar[MAXLINE];
```

This declares an array of `MAXLINE` pointers to `char`. Those pointers remain uninitialized, they don't point to valid locations, dereferencing them is **undefined behavior**. In practice, they probably point to some more-or-less "random" location and your operating system will stop you writing to some address your process isn't allowed to.

```
while ((i < MAXLINE) && ((*ar[i]) = c = getc(file)) != EOF){
//                        ^ undefined behavior

    if (c != '\n'){
        printf("%c",c);
        (*ar[i])++;
```

Why do you increment the character `a[i]` points to? You probably want to advance by one in the non-existent "string" `a[i]` is supposed to point to. You'd need another pointer for *that*, otherwise your program would "forget" where your string starts.

---

Following a working program based on your original structure, but using `fgets` and static buffers. If you need to allocate memory dynamically or if you for some reason insist on reading character by character, this is left as an exercise.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 10
#define LINEBUFSIZE 1024

int main()
{
    FILE *file;
    int i = 0;
    char ar[MAXLINE][LINEBUFSIZE];

    file = fopen("/Users/ykeshet/Desktop/lab/alice30.txt", "r");
    if (!file) return 1;

    while ((i < MAXLINE)
    {
         // read in next "line" by giving a pointer to the
         // first element as buffer for fgets():
         if (!fgets(&(arr[i++][0]), LINEBUFSIZE, file)) break; 
    }
    fclose(file);
    // i now holds the number of lines actually read.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I've changed the array declaration to a two dimensional array (char ar[MAXLINE][LINEBUFSIZE]), and it works flawlessly.

Comment: @ykesh of course the macro name was just an example, use whatever is most descriptive for your situation. If you want an array of pointers instead, you *can* allocate memory for each of them using `malloc()`. In case you didn't notice yet, you *can* [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you want. This gives some reputation points to the author and also a little bit to yourself, and it helps future readers to directly find a useful answer.

Answer (score 3):

What Felix Palmen said but also note this line :

```
file = fopen("/Users/ykeshet/Desktop/lab/alice30.txt", "read");
```

In fopen()'s specification there's no "read" mode. There's "r", "r+", but no "read".

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/

I'm using GCC 5.3.0 and trying to open a file with "read" breaks the program, so you might want to be careful.

Comment: thanks, I didn't spot *this* kind of "creative" error ;) -- fixing at least my answer not to contain it due to code copy&paste

Answer (score 0):

this line:

```
char *ar[MAXLINE];
```

declares an array of 10 pointers to char.

However, those pointers are never set to point to some memory

But that does not matter near as much as the problem that the code is reading the input into that array of pointers.
It should be reading the input into where the pointers point, however that requires that the pointers actually point to memory that the application owns.

the following:

1. cleanly compiles
2. properly checks for errors (but does not always handle them correctly as the code should cleanup at any/every exit point
3. documents why each header file is included
4. indents the code for readability by us humans
5. for readability, applies appropriate horizontal spacing
6. for readability, separates code blocks via a single blank line
7. only declares variables at (or just before) they are used.
8. uses the source code file `untitled1.c` for the input.
9. uses `#define` statements to give any 'magic' numbers meaningful names.
10. the 'while()' loop will exit if line too long or too many lines or EOF encountered
11. uses a valid second parameter to the call to `fopen()`.

The following code is one way to implement the functionality::

```
#include <stdio.h>  // fopen(), fclose(), perror(), printf(), putc()
#include <stdlib.h> // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE, malloc(), free()


// prototypes
void cleanup(  FILE *fp, char **ar );


#define MAXLINE 100
#define MAX_LEN 100


int main( void )
{
    char **ar = calloc( MAXLINE, sizeof( char* ) );

    for( size_t i=0; i<MAXLINE; i++)
    {
        ar[i] = malloc( MAX_LEN );
        if( !ar[i] )
        { // then malloc failed
            perror( "malloc failed" );
            cleanup( NULL, ar );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, malloc successful
    }


    FILE *fp = fopen("untitled1.c", "r");
    if( !fp )
    { // then fopen failed
        perror( "fopen failed" );
        cleanup( fp, ar );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    size_t col = 0;   // 'size_t' because value will never be <0
    size_t row = 0;   // "
    int c;

    while ( (row < MAXLINE)
        &&  (col < MAX_LEN )
        &&  ( (c = getc(fp)) != EOF) )
    {
        if (c != '\n')
        { // normal char read
            ar[row][col] = (char)c;
            col++;
        }

        else
        { // newline read
            // terminate the row
            ar[row][col] = '\0';
            row++;     // step to next row
            col = 0;   // reset to first column of new row
        }

        // echo byte read from file to terminal
        printf("%c",c);
    }

    putc('\n', stdout);

    cleanup( fp, ar );
} // end function: main


void cleanup(  FILE *fp, char **ar )
{
    if( NULL != fp )
    {
        fclose( fp );
    }

    for( size_t i = 0; i < MAXLINE; i++ )
    {
        free( ar[i] );
    }
} // end function: cleanup
```

Comment: "*But that does not matter near as much as the problem that the code is reading the input into that array of pointers.*" -- that's not true. There's a dereference after indexing everywhere in the original code.